# Trouble using fscanf() in c

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I am making a program in C on banking record system. I was trying to read bank info from a file in which every line represents an account and has its info [each field separated by a colon(:)] and storing that info in an array of structs. The file reading part of code is shown below:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s : %s : %s : %d : %s : %ld : %s : %s : %f :\n",
    accounts[j].bank_name, accounts[j].bank_branch, accounts[j].IFSC_code,
    &accounts[j].acc_number, accounts[j].acc_holder_name, &accounts[j].aadhar_no,
    accounts[j].holder_address, accounts[j].address_proof, &accounts[j].balance) != EOF) {
        j++;
    }
```

It works erroneously, some parts being read and some not. Moreover I am not able to capture sentences in char arrays. I am not sure how to use the `"%[^\n]%*c"` thing we used in scanf() to do so.

Please help me out if you can.

Comment: You should check, if all conversions succeeded (`fscanf(...) == 9`) instead of waiting for EOF. If the conversions were less than 9, print out how many succeeded to see, which one exactly failed. A more robust method could be to use `fgets()` to read a whole line and then use `sscanf()` to parse it. This way you won't have trouble if a single line conversion fails.

Comment: And as you said, you cannot scan a string containing whitespace with `%s`. This is a very fragile and hard way to parse input; it's better to read a whole line at a time with `fgets()`, then parse that line. Then whitespace management is in your hands, and there is no hidden buffers eating your data.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: "I am not sure how to use the "%[^\n]%*c"" --> Do not use that.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: If the fields are colon-separated, you probably need to replace each `%s` with a `%[^:]` scan set, preferably with a length so you don't get buffer overflows (`%19[^:]` is the buffer variable is of length 20).